# How to add android:allowBackup="false" via cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, android-manifest, cordova-plugins

I am now developing a `Cordova Plugin`, I wanna add

```
  android:allowBackup="true"
```

into `AndroidManifest.xml`, but I do not know how to specify it in `plugin.xml`.

Comment: same to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27550060/add-androidname-something-to-androidmanifest-xml-application-tag-from-cordo

Answer (score 22):

Answer [shared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49929216/2405040) by @Muhammad Omar works for **cordova-android < 7**. But things changed for **cordova-android >= 7**

https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/12/04/cordova-android-7.0.0.html

So you need to change it a bit for

#### cordova-android >= 7

```
<platform name="android">
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
        <application android:allowBackup="false"/>
    </edit-config>
</platform>
```

#### cordova-android < 7

The configuration edit that has worked for me was:

```
<platform name="android">
    <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/application" mode="merge">
        <application android:allowBackup="false"/>
    </edit-config>
</platform>
```

Comment: Faced an issue due to the higher cordova version, solved with the first way :)

Answer (score 18):

The configuration edit that has worked for me was:

```
<platform name="android">
    <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/application" mode="merge">
        <application android:allowBackup="false"/>
    </edit-config>
</platform>
```

**EDIT Feb-2020:**
Please refer to answer from [@Shashank Agrawal below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54997687/1084619) for **cordova-android >= 7**

Comment: Worked well in config.xml too! (cordova-android 6.4; cordova 7.1)

Answer (score 11):

To avoid android app from restoring backup on install, following config added to config.xml.

Ensure xml namespace is defined. Cordova build failed without this for me.

Solved by adding below.

```
<platform name="android">
    <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <application android:allowBackup="false" />
    </edit-config>
</platform>
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to do it via hooks (below is an example for Ionic app):

**In your config.xml add a hook as:**

`<platform name="android">
    <hook type="before_plugin_install" src="hooks/androidBeforeInstall.js" />`

**In hooks folder create the js file androidBeforeInstall.js and add this below code:**

```
module.exports = function(ctx) {
  var fs = ctx.requireCordovaModule('fs'),
  path = ctx.requireCordovaModule('path'),
  xml = ctx.requireCordovaModule('cordova-common').xmlHelpers;

 var manifestPath = path.join(ctx.opts.projectRoot, 'platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml');
 var doc = xml.parseElementtreeSync(manifestPath);
 if (doc.getroot().tag !== 'manifest') {
    throw new Error(manifestPath + ' has incorrect root node name (expected "manifest")');
 }

 doc.getroot().find('./application').attrib['android:allowBackup'] = "true";

 //write the manifest file
 fs.writeFileSync(manifestPath, doc.write({
    indent: 4
 }), 'utf-8');
};
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're writing a plugin that needs to add/edit something in the app's AndroidManifest.xml, there is functionality built into plugin.xml to do this. It should be something like this for the question example:

```
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/application" mode="merge">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" />
</edit-config>
```

[Check out the docs for config-file and edit-config](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#config-file)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simpler example, but it requires the [cordova custom config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config) plugin.

```
<platform name="android">
  <preference name="android-manifest/application/@android:allowBackup" value="true" />
</platform>`
```

Comment: Tried but didnt work for me. What did work was: 
    <platform name="android">
        <custom-preference name="android-manifest/application/@android:allowBackup" value="false" />

Answer (score 3):

First make sure that your  looks something like this: (to import android)

```
<widget id="com.myapp" version="0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

Then in your android section

```
<platform name="android">
   ...
   ...
   <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
        <application android:allowBackup="false" />
    </edit-config>
```

Note: This edit config section can be used to make many changes to your AndroidManifest.xml

And in case anyone was wondering, something similar for iOS can be achieved by adding this under the  section:

```
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I used the plugin [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config)

```
cordova plugin add cordova-custom-config
```

and the problem was solved.

In the config.xml to aggregate

```
<platform name="android">
...
    <custom-preference name="android-manifest/application/@android:allowBackup" value="false" />
...
</platform>
```

view more detail of plugin in a example in [cordova-custom-config-example](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config-example/blob/master/config.xml)

and documentation of andoid in [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#allowbackup)

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers worked for me for latest `cordova version 8.1.2`. Below is how I did it and working perfectly fine. In similar way you can also update any other configuration of `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
        <application android:allowBackup="false" />
    </edit-config>
```

You are done!

Answer (score 1):

Using edit-config breaks plugins so use it with care and test all plugins afterwards.

More info:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13514

What works without breaking plugins is by using the following (REQUIRES cordova-custom-config)

```
<platform name="android">
    <custom-preference name="android-manifest/application/@android:allowBackup" value="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Android**

edit `"platforms/android/CordovaLib/AndroidManifest.xml"` like

```
 <manifest  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  ...>
   // ... exiting conf directives ....

     <application android:allowBackup="false"/>
 </manifest>
```

or edit `"platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml"`

```
<application   // exiting attributes 
     android:allowBackup="false"
 > </application>
```