# ionic 4 - add usesCleartextTraffic permission

Tags: android, ionic-framework, permissions, ionic4

From Android 9, Android blocks cleartext traffic (HTTP), unless the app explicitly allows it in the configuration.

I added `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to the application field in AndroidManifest.xml and it works successfully.

The question is, what is the correct way to allow clear text HTTP traffic in ionic?

I believe edit the AndroidManifest manually is not the correct way.

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/q/45940861/7666442 and this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/55074899/7666442

Comment: Thanks but these answers are for regular development with Android. I don't know if this is the right way for ionic development

Answer (score 0):

[Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic) states:

> Indicates whether the app intends to use cleartext network traffic, such as cleartext HTTP. The default value is "true".

So basically this is the official way to implement and explicitly allows `HTTP` traffic

To check at runtime if the ClearText is permitted use [NetworkSecurityPolicy.isCleartextTrafficPermitted()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy.html#isCleartextTrafficPermitted()) method.

**EDIT**

If you want to modify AndroidManifest.xml in ionic the must [visit this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32394342/4079010)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this was true until Android 8.1 (API level 27). Starting with Android 9 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default. See this https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted

Comment: @RefaelJan Please read your question again what you have asked ??

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I think I wrote it very clear: The question is, what is the correct way to allow clear text HTTP traffic in ionic?

Comment: Adding it in the **AndroidManifest.xml** is the correct way

Comment: if you declare this in the manifest file you are allowing HTTP traffic

Comment: As I wrote, I edit the manifest and it work but this is not how things should be changed in ionic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194425/discussion-between-refaeljan-and-rahul-khurana).

Comment: @RefaelJan if your problem is resolved then don't forget to accept and upvote the answer